# MultipartFile is empty during rest api POST of Javascript file upload

Tags: reactjs, rest, file-upload, axios, multipartform-data

I am using React JS to upload a file.
This is the file array object i am trying to send as a POST request:

[image]

I am trying to submit a POST request via axios:

[image]

The file i am sending is not empty:
[image]
[image]

But as soon as the debugged code reaches the back-end, (REST API) the MultipartFile[] is empty
[image]
[image]

I wonder why.. Maybe i am missing some configuration here? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i already figured it out.

I should append the files as:

```
bodyFormData.append('files', files[0]);
```

not

```
bodyFormData.append('files', files);
```

This solved my problem.